Use Airflow sshoperator to run Airflow DAG on HPC which TOTP for connection
I am a bit new to airflow. I am trying to run dag using celeryExecutor. I want to run the task using online HPC CPU with SSHoperator. However, my problem lies with the ssh connection. Aside from username and password, the SSH connection requires TOTP. this is where I get the problem.
While the connection needs to be executed within airflow, airflow does not allow interrective OTP imputation.
I have tried different things. I tried initiating the connection before running airflow scheduler, then save the ssh client object somewhere so that I can pull the client object when I run airflow scheduler, but ssh client object cannot be saved.
I also tried using a task to initaite the connection, using airlfow Variable.get() approach to input the otp to ensure connection to HPC, but I cannot pass teh client object to teh next task becuase I cannot serialize the client object and deserialize it.
Has anyone encountered this problem. does anyone know the solution?
I am trying to connect, and expect the airflow task to run on the HPC CPU
